# Detect width using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to obtain the width of each `<li>` within the main navigation bar which can be obtained from the main LI. Whilst the below code works it seems to apply the same width to the following LI's rather than detecting it's own individual size.

How would I go about making this dynamic please?

```
$('.navbar-nav-middle li').width($('.navbar-nav-middle a').parent().width());
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use contextual `this` enclosed with a function here:

```
$('.navbar-nav-middle li').width(function () {
  return $(this).find("a").parent().width()
});
```

This might still give the same thing, as `<li>` takes up its content's width.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much. Worked a treat!

Comment: @Bradley Glad to help mate.

Comment: I'd like to ask, if the user was to resize the screen viewport if we could have this redetect the new LI width if at all possible? as when it hits certain breakpoints the LI may have a smaller font size setting so the width might be slightly less?

Comment: @Bradley You can detect the resize of window: `$(window).resize(function () { ... })`... Using `@media` queries is the best for this.